# Android Layout - Image taking up extra space

Tags: android, image, layout

I've added an image to my xml file. This is the code that I am using:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/topbar_logo2x"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <TabHost
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dip"
                android:background="#000" />

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want my TabHost to be exactly on top of my image. When I checked up some answers in StackOverflow, I got an answer that stated to use

```xml
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

I want to use both `android:scaleType="fitStart"` and `android:scaleType="fitEnd"` on the same ImageView and that is not possible as Sndroid will allow only one declaration of `scaleType`. How will I be able to attain the same with change in code ? Is there some other command that will help me?

[image]

Comment: So you want `TabHost` to be above the `ImageView`? Howabout moving `TabHost` above it in the xml?

Comment: no Jarno, I want my Image to be at the top of the page (company logo) followed by the TabHost

Comment: no Jarno, I want my Image to be at the top of the page (company logo) followed by the TabHost

Comment: Could you show a screenshot how you want it and how it's now displayed? Your question does not contain enough information to help you...

Comment: Sorry for the late response Jarno. I've attached the image in the question please go through it.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't see it, where is it?

Comment: Terribly Sorry, I was working and forgot about the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me the larger black line must come from the image (topbar_logo2x) or the way it is scaled into the `ImageView`. Try using `scaleType="fitXY"` to see if the above black line vanishes. If not, then post the image for us to look.

Seems to me the `View` below `LinearLayout` causes the smaller black line. Remove it.